# Jmeter how can get match product in CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have a CSV file like "productid,brandid" and i can get brandid from a previously response and save in variable like ${brandid_response}. Now i want to get only one first match "productid" from many rows in CSV with condition "brandid==${brandid_response}".

Can anyone help me in this case? Thank you so much.

Comment: When script find out first match row, it will stop to run.

Comment: Any logic you implement to parse and search your CSV will be resource intensive to execute per thread. You should probably stick your CSV in a simple database or in-memory key-value store like redis and query it for `brandid`.

Comment: Hi , any feedback on answer? thx

Answer (score 0):

As @RaGe has commented, what you are trying to do with standard jmeter elements would not perform correctly.

A better option is to used a Key/Value backend that could return the value for the key.

Another option is to use a Setup Thread Group to load in a HashMap the brandId <=> ProductId mapping and then use a JSR223PreProcessor + Groovy to get this value from the Map and store it as a variable using:

> vars.put ("productId", map.get(vars["brandId"]));

where map is your initially loaded HashMap.